# wpf how to use a converter for child bindings of multibinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters, multibinding

I need a multibinding of bunch boolean properties but with inversing some of these like an example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanAndConverter}">
            <Binding Path="IsInitialized"/>
            <Binding Path="IsFailed" Converter="{StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </StackPanel.IsEnabled>
</StackPanel.IsEnabled>
```

But I got a `InvalidOperationException` from a `InverseBooleanConverter` with message "The target must be a boolean". My InverseBooleanConverter is:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and BooleanAndConverter is:

```
public class BooleanAndConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.All(value => (!(value is bool)) || (bool) value);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("BooleanAndConverter is a OneWay converter.");
    }
}
```

So, how to use a converters with child bindings?

Comment: You know you're throwing the exception yourself? Don't check the `targetType`. Check if `value` is bool, than return the inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to check the `targetType`, just check the type of `value` passed into Convert method.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                      object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (!(value is bool))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Value is not bool");

    return !(bool)value;
}
```