# Manage the targetType of a Binding in a MultiBinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, converters

So, I have a multi-binding with a converter that takes in some values and finds the max of them. The problem is that one of the bindings utilises a converter that expects a `double` target type, while the binding has an `object` target type. I was wondering if there was any way to modify the target type of a binding in any way.

Below is an approximation of my xaml:

```xaml
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Width>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource _maxValueConverter}">
      <Binding Source="{StaticResource _constantZeroValue}"/>
      <Binding Path="ActualWidth"
               ElementName="_previousTextBlock"
               Converter="{StaticResource _requiresDoubleTargetConverter}"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Width>
</TextBlock>
```

So basically if there is any way to tell the second binding that it is outputting to a double value, that'd be great.

Minimal Verifiable Complete Example:

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <StackPanel>
      <StackPanel.Resources>
         <sys:Double x:Key="constantZero">0</sys:Double>
         <local:RequiresDoubleTargetConverter x:Key="requiresDoubleTargetConverter" />
         <local:MaxValueConverter x:Key="maxValueConverter" />
      </StackPanel.Resources>

      <Border x:Name="topBorder"
              BorderThickness="1"
              BorderBrush="Black"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left">
         <TextBlock x:Name="topTextBlock"
                    Background="Aqua"
                    Text="{Binding TopText}" />
      </Border>

      <Border BorderThickness="1"
              BorderBrush="Black"
              MinWidth="100"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left">
         <TextBlock Background="ForestGreen"
                 Text="{Binding BottomText}"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 MinWidth="100">
            <TextBlock.Width>

               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource maxValueConverter}">
                  <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                     <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="topTextBlock" Converter="{StaticResource requiresDoubleTargetConverter}" />
                     <Binding Source="{StaticResource constantZero}" />
                  </MultiBinding.Bindings>
               </MultiBinding>

            </TextBlock.Width>
         </TextBlock>
      </Border>

   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```c#
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public string TopText
      {
         get { return "Hello World!"; }
      }

      public string BottomText
      {
         get { return "hi earth."; }
      }

      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }
   }

   public class RequiresDoubleTargetConverter : IValueConverter
   {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         // I am looking for a way to manually ensure that "targetType == typeof(double)" evaluates to true.
         if (targetType != typeof(double))
         {
            return null;
         }
         else
         {
            // Actual converter performs this calculation.
            return (double)value - 14;
         }
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         // Irrelevant method for our purposes.
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
   }

   public class MaxValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
   {
      public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         double max = double.NegativeInfinity;
         foreach (object value in values)
         {
            if (value is double)
            {
               max = Math.Max((double)value, max);
            }
            else
            {
               Debug.Fail("All values must be doubles");
            }
         }

         return max;
      }

      public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         // Irrelevant method for our purposes.
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
   }
}
```

This was created using Visual Studio 2015, and is verified to show the erroneous behaviour. What I am trying to determine is if it is possible to manually set the `targetType` of the `RequiresDoubleTargetConverter` from the xaml.

Comment: Instead of checking the `targetType`, better check the type of the `value` parameter and provide an appropriately converted value, e.g. as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27080733/1136211

Comment: I'm trying to avoid changes to the second converter as it is used in a lot of places in our application, and I'd need to do a fair bit of analysis before making changes.

Comment: Good tip about using the incoming type.  The only issue is if that value is a null, since you'll be blind to what that type is.

Answer (score 0):

Bindings operate on `object`, as far as the type system is concerned. If you want a specific type, you'll need to ensure that yourself.

However you could use the target type passed to the converter to determine which type is required, and modify the converter's return value accordingly.

Comment: So is there a way to set the target type of the converter manually, or am I stuck with it being `object`?

Comment: "you could use the target type passed to the converter to determine which type is required, and modify the converter's return value accordingly" - this is probably what OP already does, and their problem is that the target type passed to the converter is `object` here, because the Binding is part of a MultiBinding.

Comment: Exactly, is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

> So is there a way to set the target type of the converter manually, or am I stuck with it being object?

You are stuck with it being `object` as the signature of the `Convert` method is always the same, i.e. it accepts an `object[]` of values and nothing else.

You will have to cast `values[1]` to a `double` in your `Convert` method (because the method will always and only be passed values of type `object`):

```
double d = (double)values[1];
```

Comment: I'm afraid this misses the point of the question. Yes the type of the provided values is `object` but it also has a `targetType` parameter. Currently `targetType == typeof(object)` is true, but I want a way to make `targetType == typeof(double)` evaluate to true instead.

Comment: So you are saying that the targetType parameter of the IMultiValueConverter doesn't return typeof(double)? Please include an example that verifies this then: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a way around this, but it only works if you have access to the converter you're using on the MultiBinding itself (or you can add one.) as well as a little extra effort if it also uses a ConverterParameter, TargetNullValue and/or a StringFormat.

The trick is when you add the child Binding to the MultiBinding, you remove the Converter, ConverterParameter, TargetNullValue and StringFormat values from that child binding and store them somewhere that's accessible by the Convert method for the MultiBinding's converter. (We use a wrapper MarkupExtension to simulate the MultiBinding so we have access to everything before they're actually applied as once they are, you can't change them.)

Then in the MultiBinding's Convert method, you're now getting the raw, not-yet-converted/formatted/coalesced value from the child binding, but you also have the ultimate target that you need (double in this example) as it was handed to the Convert method for the MultiBinding that you're in.

With that information, you then call the child converter's Convert method manually, passing in the not-yet-converted value, the targetType (passed in to you), and the childConverterParameter.

You take the result of that call, and if null, return the TargetNullValue from the child binding.

If it's not null and both targetType is a string and you have a String Format, finally format the results.

Here's pseudo-code (i.e. off the top of my head. Probably lots of syntax errors, etc. For the actual code, you can see me using it in my `DynamicResourceBinding` class that I have up on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49159501/168179).)

```
// Convert function for the MultiBinding
private object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, Culture culture){

    var rawChildBindingResult = values[0]; // assuming it's in the first position

    var convertedChildBindingResult = childConverter(rawChildBindingResult, targetType, childConverterParameter, culture);

    if(convertedChildBindingResult == null)
        convertedChildBindingResult = childTargetNullValue;
    else if(targetType == typeof(string) && childStringFormat != null)
        convertedChildBindingResult = string.Format(childStringFormat, convertedChildBindingResult);

    // Now do whatever you would with the 'convertedChildBindingResult' as if things were normal
}
```

Again, take a look at the link to see it in context.