# Is it possible to pass the targetType of a MultiBinding to the child bindings' converters?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, multibinding

We have an odd case where a `Binding` that's used as child of a `MultiBinding` needs its `Converter`s `Convert` method to know the ultimate data type the `MultiBinding` is bound to.

For a regular `Binding` with a `Converter`, if it's bound to the `Text` property of a `TextBlock`, the `Convert` method will receive `System.string` in its `targetType` argument.

However if that same `Binding` is instead added as a child of a `MultiBinding`, even if that `MultiBinding` is assigned to a `Text` property itself, all child `Binding`'s `Converter`'s `Convert` methods will receive `System.object` as the `targetType` argument, not `System.string`. This kind of makes sense as technically their target is now the `MultiBinding`, not the `Text` property.

Still, I'm wondering if it can be set up so that information is passed through to the child `Bindings`. I'm thinking no, but I figured if anyone would know, it would be the S.O. community.

Comment: You've seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42784793/1136211

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that, but its conclusions don't apply here where we're controlling the MarkupExtension and thus the MultiBinding ourselves.  I actually have a plan... grabbing the converter from the child binding and storing it in a variable, then removing it from that child binding, then manually calling it from within the converter on the multi binding where we're handed the now-unconverted value as one of the inputs.  Then we simply pass the correct type through, additionally handling TargetNullValue as well.   Testing now and will post as an answer if to works.

Comment: Oh how I love down-votes for no good reason!  I'm gonna suggest people who down-vote without explanation get banned from doing so, or at least make it a requirement they enter something.

Comment: *"its conclusions don't apply here where we're controlling the MarkupExtension and thus the MultiBinding ourselves"* - there is no mention of that in the question, so how should anybody have taken that into account without having read your recent StackOverflow posts? Even with that knowledge it would have been hard to judge if that is actually what you're after.

Comment: I didn't want to restrict my question to our specific use-case.  You asked me had I seen that article, and I replied I did, but it didn't apply to my specific scenario, hence I asked the question myself slightly differently.  That's all. Not trying to downplay your link.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so... the short answer is 'No, you can't!' However, the long answer is 'Yes you can, with a bit of work!'

The trick is instead of letting the child Binding handle the converter, you manually call it from the MultiBinding's own converter.

I've actually written a pretty long explanation of how all this works here on StackOverflow.com in the following answer:

[How to create a DynamicResourceBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49159501/168179).

Specifically, check out both the `ProvideValue` and the `WrapperConvert` functions. Lots of comments explaining what's going on and why.